# How to label Excel X and Y axes in 2d graph

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, excel, vba

I am stumped on a problem that seems easy, labeling X and Y axes!

I am creating an Excel graph inside VS2010 with C#.  It is a 2D XY scatter chart.  But I can't control the label of the X axis!  I can only control the label of the Y axis!  I have spent too much time trying to figure this one out and have given up.  So I'm looking for someone's help!  Here's my code:

```
    private void showExcelXY_v2()
    {
        xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        xla.Visible = true;
        Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

        // Now create the chart.
        ChartObjects chartObjs = (ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        ChartObject chartObj = chartObjs.Add(100, 20, 500, 300);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart xlChart = chartObj.Chart;

        //add some data from your datasource like a dataset or like below.
        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Value of n";
        ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Term";


        ws.Cells[2, 1] = "0";
        ws.Cells[2, 2] = "0";

        ws.Cells[3, 1] = "9181";
        ws.Cells[3, 2] = "0";

        ws.Cells[4, 1] = "9181";
        ws.Cells[4, 2] = "-377094";

        ws.Cells[5, 1] = "0";
        ws.Cells[5, 2] = "-377094";

        ws.Cells[6, 1] = "-9554";
        ws.Cells[6, 2] = "-329688";

        ws.Cells[7, 1] = "-9554";
        ws.Cells[7, 2] = "0";

        ws.Cells[8, 1] = "0";
        ws.Cells[8, 2] = "0";


        //set the source data and the chart type.
        Range chartRange = ws.get_Range("A2", "B" + "8");
        xlChart.SetSourceData(chartRange, Type.Missing);
        xlChart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines;

        // Customize axes:
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis xAxis = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        xAxis.HasTitle = true;
        xAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Above         Pressure (psi)          Below";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis yAxis = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        yAxis.MajorTickMark = XlTickMark.xlTickMarkCross;
        yAxis.HasTitle = true;
        yAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Compression (lbf)";

        // Add title:
        xlChart.HasTitle = true;
        xlChart.ChartTitle.Text = "XPak Performance Envelope" + '\n' + "(Open Top & Bottom)";

        // Remove legend:
        xlChart.HasLegend = false;
    }
```

The result of this code, as you step through it, shows the X axis label goes to the Y axis, then it is overwritten by the Y axis label.  Nothing goes to the X axis!  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have both axes defined the same way:

```
xAxis = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary)

yAxis = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary)
```

The x-Axis is the "Category" axis and the y-Axis is the "Value" axis. Try this for the x-Axis (revised):

```
xAxis = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary)
```

Comment: David, Thank you.  You got me past this nightmare!  I had to rearrange the order of your suggestion, putting (XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlGroup.xlValue) for it to be accepted, but that fixed my problem!